# Trouble linking clients DocuSign accounts via API

Tags: docusignapi

I am developing an integration using the DocuSign REST API. Users of our application can have their clients apply for credit, and then have them sign the application with DocuSign. We want to be able to have these documents be linked to our clients DocuSign account, rather than to ours. Our account type is "Developer Start-Up API". We currently have an approved integrator key and account, the only part that we are having trouble with is linking our customers accounts to ours. Basically, where do pass on the customer credentials?

Answer (score 0):

This question is more an architecture question than an code how to for Stack Overflow.

Given this is the case:

1. My assumption is that the document templates are for the credit apps are in your account and you want to send the actual envelope from the "clients" DocuSign account using their credentials which is possible.
2. Generally this would require using DocuSign OAuth tokens for the client account access to send and a service account credentials to access your account for templates containing your pdf bytes.
3. Below is a gross overview sequence diagram to outline the above

[Sequence Diagram link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM2sl.png)